# Keras evaluate() and predict() results are way too off

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, text-classification

Im working on a binary classification model using keras. See data set up below

```
print(train_x.shape) --(79520,)
print(test_x.shape) --(26507,)
print(train_y.shape) --(79520,)
print(test_y.shape) --(26507,)
```

Im using LSTM, activation is 'sigmoid' and 'binary_crossentrophy' is my loss function.

```
input_layer = layers.Input((100,))
embedding_layer = layers.Embedding(20001, 100)(input_layer)
lstm_layer = layers.Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(64,return_sequences=True))(embedding_layer)
pooling_layer = layers.GlobalMaxPool1D()(lstm_layer)
op_layer = layers.Dense(50, activation='relu')(pooling_layer)
op_layer = layers.Dropout(0.5)(op_layer)
op_layer = layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')(op_layer)
model = models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=op_layer)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 100, 100)          2000100   
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_1 (Bidirection (None, 100, 128)          84992     
_________________________________________________________________
global_max_pooling1d_1 (Glob (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 50)                6450      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 50)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 51        
=================================================================
Total params: 2,091,593
Trainable params: 2,091,593
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

At end of 10 epochs, training accuracy is 0.97 and validation accuracy is around 0.72.

```
model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=10, batch_size=10, validation_split = 0.1)

 Train on 71568 samples, validate on 7952 samples
Epoch 1/10
71568/71568 [==============================] - 114s 2ms/step - loss: 0.6014 - acc: 0.6603 - val_loss: 0.5556 - val_acc: 0.7006
Epoch 2/10
71568/71568 [==============================] - 107s 1ms/step - loss: 0.4921 - acc: 0.7573 - val_loss: 0.5449 - val_acc: 0.7194
Epoch 3/10
71568/71568 [==============================] - 107s 1ms/step - loss: 0.3918 - acc: 0.8179 - val_loss: 0.5924 - val_acc: 0.7211
Epoch 4/10
71568/71568 [==============================] - 107s 2ms/step - loss: 0.3026 - acc: 0.8667 - val_loss: 0.6642 - val_acc: 0.7248
Epoch 5/10
71568/71568 [==============================] - 107s 1ms/step - loss: 0.2363 - acc: 0.8963 - val_loss: 0.7322 - val_acc: 0.7271
Epoch 6/10
71568/71568 [==============================] - 107s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1939 - acc: 0.9155 - val_loss: 0.8349 - val_acc: 0.7150
Epoch 7/10
71568/71568 [==============================] - 107s 2ms/step - loss: 0.1621 - acc: 0.9292 - val_loss: 1.0337 - val_acc: 0.7226
Epoch 8/10
71568/71568 [==============================] - 107s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1417 - acc: 0.9375 - val_loss: 0.9998 - val_acc: 0.7221
Epoch 9/10
71568/71568 [==============================] - 107s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1273 - acc: 0.9433 - val_loss: 1.1732 - val_acc: 0.7197
Epoch 10/10
71568/71568 [==============================] - 107s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1138 - acc: 0.9481 - val_loss: 1.1462 - val_acc: 0.7222

scores = model.evaluate(test_x,test_y, verbose=1)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

26507/26507 [==============================] - 5s 183us/step
acc: 72.45%
```

Every thing seem to be good till this point and it goes south when i run predict() function on the test data

```
pred=model.predict(test_x)
pred=pred.argmax(axis=-1)
print(accuracy_score(pred,test_y)*100)

43.48285358584525

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix(test_y, pred)

array([[11526,     0],
       [14981,     0]])
```

Im not able to understand why evaluate() and predict() results are way too off. Can you please point of what's wrong? Im running this on a GPU EC2 instance. Version of software below.

Keras 2.2.4
Tensorflow 1.12.0

Let me know if ay other detail about the model is needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your `acc` and `val_acc` are so far apart from each other suggests your model is heavily over-training. Generally speaking you want to have a model where `acc` and `val_acc` are both close to each other. Worse yet, the discrapency between `loss` and `val_loss` is dramatic and `val_loss` is unstable and increasing as the experiment progress epoch-by-epoch. This is the type of thing you would want to be looking for in training a model. It's well worth the time learning a little about over-training and under-training and how to deal with those situations.

Moreover, accuracy is typically a weak metric for binary classification tasks, so it may not be a good basis for training a model in the first place. Better use something like f1-score instead, unless your true and false labels are near to 50/50. You can find recall, precision, and f1 for Keras [here](https://github.com/autonomio/talos/blob/master/talos/metrics/keras_metrics.py).

Comment: Thanks for your input, i will do my research and update here